# Social media in 'Coming Soon' pages

Tags: buttons, social-media

I was setting up a 'Coming Soon page' for a client, with an email field for users to register for updates and links to the FB page and Twitter account of the Web app. Their concept isn't ground breaking, their USP is their tie-ups (which will probably be confirmed AFTER their soft launch).

The debate is about having FB Share and Tweet buttons. A user may want to signup, but not sure if they are likely to 'stamp their approval' by sharing it.

Not having those buttons will definitely reduce clutter on the page and make the 'email' the only call-to-action.

Is there any research on weather these social interactions are useful for a 'Coming Soon' page?

Comment: How about not showing the share buttons until after signing up? The reasoning is: I don't care about sharing unless I care about signing up. You don't know that until I've chosen to sign up. That way you'll get higher conversion on the sharing buttons and fewer annoyed people.

Comment: I like the thought process behind this, will probably implement in this manner. How can I 'accept' this answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about not showing the share buttons until after signing up? The reasoning is: I don't care about sharing unless I care about signing up. You don't know that until I've chosen to sign up. That way you'll get higher conversion on the sharing buttons and fewer annoyed people.

Answer (score 0):

Remember [Pottermore?](http://www.pottermore.com/) Google Plus? (Or Gabbo!) Assuming people do actually care about it enough to share it, social media is great for these sorts of things. Fab.com had a similar "Coming soon" campaign I never personally would have heard of if it weren't for social media. In the relevant circles these things really make the rounds, though I'm afraid I can't point to direct research on the matter.

To call users "lazy" would be unfair and overly simplistic, but remember you should do anything and *everything* to make their job easier, and social media buttons transforms a large number of steps (find address bar, copy it, open facebook, paste into facebook, explain link, hit button....) into a single step (click button). The reason Twitter grew so fast is because it makes things easy to share, not because you couldn't share before.
Also, don't forget people don't like giving out their emails, but they'll hit "like" and "retweet" like mad.

Edit: Also, to be blunt, what more do they have to *do* on your "Coming Soon" page beyond get psyched for it themselves and hopefully get other people psyched? A Coming Soon page with a single option (the email option) would be the last place I would worry about clutter

Comment: I wouldn't generally share/tweet a service that I've personally not used and thats not because I'm lazy. As I'd mentioned, the 'wow' factor behind the idea is not even up and neither is it backed by Google or JK Rowling, so are the users still likely to 'share' it? and there is no page that couldn't use 'less clutter' ;)